# jQuery Drag & Drop Image Uploader Preview PDF image if choose pdf format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple jQuery Drag & Drop Image Uploader [plugin](https://github.com/christianbayer/image-uploader).

The main function is to preview image before upload.

As you can see on that plugin link, it only can be used for preview image.

Now I have .pdf format, when I choose it I need to preview it as pdf image.

My question, how to set the function if I choose pdf then show it as pdf image?

```
/*! Image Uploader - v1.2.3 - 26/11/2019
* Copyright (c) 2019 Christian Bayer; Licensed MIT */
! function (e) {
e.fn.imageUploader = function (t) {
    let n, i = {
            preloaded: [],
            imagesInputName: "images",
            preloadedInputName: "preloaded",
            label: "Drag & Drop files here or click to browse",
            extensions: [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".pdf"],
    mimes: ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "application/pdf"]
            maxSize: void 0,
            maxFiles: void 0
        },
        a = this,
        s = new DataTransfer;
    a.settings = {}, a.init = function () {
        a.settings = e.extend(a.settings, i, t), a.each(function (t, n) {
            let i = o();
            if (e(n).append(i), i.on("dragover", r.bind(i)), i.on("dragleave", r.bind(i)), i.on("drop", p.bind(i)), a.settings.preloaded.length) {
                i.addClass("has-files");
                let e = i.find(".uploaded");
                for (let t = 0; t < a.settings.preloaded.length; t++) e.append(l(a.settings.preloaded[t].src, a.settings.preloaded[t].id, !0))
            }
        })
    };
    let o = function () {
            let t = e("<div>", {
                class: "image-uploader"
            });
            n = e("<input>", {
                type: "file",
                id: a.settings.imagesInputName + "-" + h(),
                name: a.settings.imagesInputName + "[]",
                accept: a.settings.extensions.join(","),
                multiple: ""
            }).appendTo(t);
            e("<div>", {
                class: "uploaded"
            }).appendTo(t);
            let i = e("<div>", {
                class: "upload-text"
            }).appendTo(t);
            e("<i>", {
                class: "iui-cloud-upload"
            }).appendTo(i), e("<span>", {
                text: a.settings.label
            }).appendTo(i);
            return t.on("click", function (e) {
                d(e), n.trigger("click")
            }), n.on("click", function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation()
            }), n.on("change", p.bind(t)), t
        },
        d = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(), e.stopPropagation()
        },
        l = function (t, i, o) {
            let l = e("<div>", {
                    class: "uploaded-image"
                }),
                r = (e("<img>", {
                    src: t
                }).appendTo(l), e("<button>", {
                    class: "delete-image"
                }).appendTo(l));
            e("<i>", {
                class: "iui-close"
            }).appendTo(r);
            if (o) {
                l.attr("data-preloaded", !0);
                e("<input>", {
                    type: "hidden",
                    name: a.settings.preloadedInputName + "[]",
                    value: i
                }).appendTo(l)
            } else l.attr("data-index", i);
            return l.on("click", function (e) {
                d(e)
            }), r.on("click", function (t) {
                d(t);
                let o = l.parent();
                if (!0 === l.data("preloaded")) a.settings.preloaded = a.settings.preloaded.filter(function (e) {
                    return e.id !== i
                });
                else {
                    let t = parseInt(l.data("index"));
                    o.find(".uploaded-image[data-index]").each(function (n, i) {
                        n > t && e(i).attr("data-index", n - 1)
                    }), s.items.remove(t), n.prop("files", s.files);
                }
                l.remove(), o.children().length || o.parent().removeClass("has-files")
            }), l
        },
        r = function (t) {
            d(t), "dragover" === t.type ? e(this).addClass("drag-over") : e(this).removeClass("drag-over")
        },
        p = function (t) {
            d(t);
            let i = e(this),
                o = Array.from(t.target.files || t.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files),
                l = [];
            e(o).each(function (e, t) {
                a.settings.extensions && !g(t) || a.settings.mimes && !c(t) || a.settings.maxSize && !f(t) || a.settings.maxFiles && !m(l.length, t) || l.push(t)
            }), l.length ? (i.removeClass("drag-over"), u(i, l)) : n.prop("files", s.files)
        },
        g = function (e) {
            return !(a.settings.extensions.indexOf(e.name.replace(new RegExp("^.*\\."), ".").toLowerCase()) < 0) || (alert(`The file "${e.name}" does not match with the accepted file extensions: "${a.settings.extensions.join('", "')}"`), !1)
        },
        c = function (e) {
            return !(a.settings.mimes.indexOf(e.type) < 0) || (alert(`The file "${e.name}" does not match with the accepted mime types: "${a.settings.mimes.join('", "')}"`), !1)
        },
        f = function (e) {
            return !(e.size > a.settings.maxSize) || (alert(`The file "${e.name}" exceeds the maximum size of ${a.settings.maxSize/1024/1024}Mb`), !1)
        },
        m = function (e, t) {
            return !(e + s.items.length + a.settings.preloaded.length >= a.settings.maxFiles) || (alert(`The file "${t.name}" could not be added because the limit of ${a.settings.maxFiles} files was reached`), !1)
        },
        u = function (t, n) {
            t.addClass("has-files");
            let i = t.find(".uploaded"),
                a = t.find('input[type="file"]');
            e(n).each(function (e, t) {
                s.items.add(t), i.append(l(URL.createObjectURL(t), s.items.length - 1), !1)
            }), a.prop("files", s.files)
        },
        h = function () {
            return Date.now() + Math.floor(100 * Math.random() + 1)
        };
    return this.init(), this
}
}(jQuery);
```

Show pdf icon image:

[image]

Comment: You need to use a separate library to do that. `imageUploader` will not be much of help in your case to preview pdf before uploading.

Comment: How if We use condition, if `.pdf` then use `<img src="pdf.png"/>` else ... ?

Comment: what you mean by `pdf.png` to me its just a simple file name pdf.png. If you do then you need a converter from `.pdf`  to `.png` and then display it.

Comment: As per my explanation, I just want the function show image PDF if I choose .pdf format.

Comment: Firstly, a PDF is not an image. You are mixing up things - As i said if you want your for example name.pdf file to be displayed on screen before your upload then you need to use a PDF library or a FileReader API for that.

Comment: Hi... I do not need to preview the PDF content. What I need is only show icon PDF. Please see my updated post. Sorry for missunderstanding

Comment: Can you please tell us what is a `.pdf` means to you OR this `Now I have .pdf format, when I choose it I need to preview it as pdf image` YOU CAN NOT preview a PDF file as an image - You can google it as well.